# git force update a specific directory

Tags: git

I'm using git. I've made some changes to multiple code files in a specific directory but now want the original versions. I've already copied my modified files elsewhere. How do I pull back the originals now?

Comment: `git reset HEAD <file>` This will be cumbersome if you have a lot of files in your directory.  A shell script might help as well, but that's getting beyond my comfort zone.

Comment: Can I do `git reset HEAD .` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
git stash -u
```

is the safe way of undoing changes to your files.

Answer (score 1):

Many options:

- `git stash` will reset your working copy to the latest committed version, storing your changes in case you ever want them back. You can't specify a folder with this one; it works over your entire working copy.
- `git checkout .` will revert the current folder to the index, ie the latest committed version plus anything listed as "Changes to be committed" when you do a `git status`. If you want to clear out those, too, use `git reset .` first.
- `git reset --hard` will revert everything to the latest commit, across your entire repository, regardless of whether it's been staged to be committed or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is really what branches were made for.

Instead of `stash`ing or copying the files away, create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b name-experimental-branch
```

and commit normally.

Your changes are safely away from the other branches, and no mess!

Then, to get back to the originals, just check out the branch you were on before. Probably:

```
git checkout master
```

And you're back to the original version.

Comment: The problem is that the codebase is gigantic, and I have made changes to only 3-5 files.

Comment: That's the whole point of git - tracking changes. It only stores the *changes* so it doesn't matter how big the codebase is, the branch just has your 3-5 changes overlaid on top of the main branch.

Comment: For more info about branching: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging